# Erlang generate anonymous function of an arbitary arity?

Tags: erlang, arity

Is it possible to write a function that returns an anonymous function of a specified arity? I'd like to be able to generate a function that can be passed to `meck:expect/3` as the third argument so I can dynamically mock existing functions of any arity?

I've done quite a bit of searching and it seems like the only way to solve this is by hardcoding things like this:

```erlang
gen_fun(1, Function) ->
    fun(A) -> Function([A]) end;
gen_fun(2, Function) ->
    fun(A, B) -> Function([A, B]) end;
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not pretty, but you can use the same trick as the shell and build your functions *from the ground up*:

```
-module(funny).

-export([gen_fun/1, gen_fun/2]).

-spec gen_fun(function()) -> function().
gen_fun(Function) ->
    {arity, Arity} = erlang:fun_info(Function, arity),
    gen_fun(Arity, Function).

-spec gen_fun(non_neg_integer(), function()) -> function().
gen_fun(Arity, Function) ->
    Params = [{var, 1, list_to_atom([$X| integer_to_list(I)])} || I <- lists:seq(1, Arity)],
    Anno = erl_anno:new(1),
    Expr =
        {'fun',
         Anno,
         {clauses, [{clause, Anno, Params, [], [{call, Anno, {var, Anno, 'Function'}, Params}]}]}},
    {value, Fun, _Vars} = erl_eval:expr(Expr, [{'Function', Function}]),
    Fun.
```

Then, in the shell…

```
1> F = funny:gen_fun(fun io:format/2).
#Fun<erl_eval.43.40011524>
2> F("~ts~n", [""]).

ok
3> F1 = funny:gen_fun(fun io:format/1).
#Fun<erl_eval.44.40011524>
4> F1("~n").

ok
5>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @BrujoBenavides! That solution is prettier than what I had. One thing I am encountering with this solution is a dialyzer error that I am struggling to understand:

`src/funny.erl
Line 6: Function gen_fun/1 has no local return
Line 11: Function gen_fun/2 has no local return
Line 17: The call erl_eval:expr(Expr::{'fun',1,{'clauses',[{'clause',1,[{'var',1,atom()}],[],[{'call',1,{'var',1,'Function'},[]},...]},...]}}, [{'Function',_},...]) does not have a term of type {'nil',erl_anno:anno()} | {atom(),erl_anno:anno(),_} | {'bc' | 'call' | 'case' | 'cons' | 'lc' ...`

Comment: Any idea what might be the cause of that? It doesn't appear the Erlang docs really define what the type of the first argument should be - https://erlang.org/doc/man/erl_parse.html#type-abstract_expr.

Comment: It looks like what we're building (i.e. `Expr`) doesn't have the appropriate format to be an `erl_eval:expression()` which is, in turn, just an `erl_parse:abstract_expr()`.

Comment: I fixed it using `erl_anno:new/1` for line numbers.

Comment: That fixed it, thanks!